# React useParams,find is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to match passed title from useParams with the data API data that I fetch. I can't use function find, I get error movie.find is not a function.Can you please help me?
Thank you

```
const [movie,setMovie] = useState({});

useEffect (() => {
    fetch(api_url).then(res => res.json ([]))
      .then (data => {
        setMovie(data.results) 
        console.log(movie)
      });
       }, [] ); 

const{ title }  = useParams();

const naslov = movie.title
const result = movie.find( ({ naslov }) => naslov === {title} );

return (
    <div>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: you movie is an `{}` you cannot use `find` on an object .

Comment: You can use find method only on arrays not objects

Answer (score 0):

you have set the initial state of movie to on object, can't use .find for an object literal.
maybe add the console.log output of your movie to the question.
if movie is indeed an object, convert it to array with object.keys/object.values depending on the shape of your movie object